# How to deserialize JSON string from file input

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm working on a test app to prove out some functionality and part of what I'm trying to accomplish involves a user filling out a form that, once submitted downloads a JSON file containing all the values from the form.  There there, the user then sends that JSON file to another party that will take that file and use it to fill out additional information on the form while retaining the selections from the original user.

Here's what I've got so far.

Data models

```
public class TableDemo
{
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public TableDemo()
    {
        Locations = new List<Location>();
        Locations.Add(new Location());

        Users = new List<User>();
        Users.Add(new User());
    }
}

public class Location
{
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        TableDemo model = new TableDemo();
        return View(model);
    }

    // This is where the user fills out the original form which downloads to their machine as a JSON file.
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(TableDemo model)
    {
        string jsonString;
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        };
        jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
        byte[] jsonFileArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
        return File(jsonFileArray, "application/json", "testJson.json");
    }

    // Where the second user inputs the file from the first user
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ImportForm()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // the jsonString argument is always null here
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ImportForm(string jsonString)
    {
        TableDemo model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TableDemo>(jsonString);
        return View("IndexDeserialized", model);
    }
}
```

View (ImportForm.cshtml)

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    function showFile(input) {
        let file = input.files[0];

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);

        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
            let jsonContent = $('#jsonContent');
            jsonContent.append(reader.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = function () {
            console.log(reader.error);
        };
    };
</script>
}

<body>
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" onchange="readDocument(this)" />
    </div>
    <div id="jsonContent">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

The contents of my JSON file generated from the initial view

```
{
  "Locations": [
    {
      "Street": "12345 Test Drive",
      "City": "Chicago",
      "State": "IL",
      "Zip": "55555"
    },
    {
      "Street": "12345 Test Drive",
      "City": "ABC",
      "State": "IL",
      "Zip": "60441"
    },
    {
      "Street": "1234",
      "City": "asdasd",
      "State": "asdasd",
      "Zip": "asdasd"
    }
  ],
  "Users": [
    {
      "FirstName": "asdas",
      "LastName": "dasdsa",
      "PhoneNumber": "dasd"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "sadasd",
      "LastName": "dsadas",
      "PhoneNumber": "asdasd"
    }
  ]
}
```

So from here I am a bit lost.  I've tried a few approaches where I submit the file and have a corresponding `HttpPost` action for `ImportForm` that take either a `string` for the JSON string or even an `IFormFile` for just submitting the entire file to be deserialized once I've got it in memory.

I don't want to keep the files anywhere and I was trying to just pull the actual JSON text directly from the file, deserialize that back into a `TableDemo` object and navigate to a new page with the values populated but all attempts lead to either dead ends where I need to have a file path (which, again I don't want to store these files anywhere) or I get null objects when attempting to just send the JSON string to the controller action.

**How can I simply take the contents of the JSON file, deserialize back into a `TableDemo` object and display those values on a new page?**

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ So say I've got just a simple `@model string` for my view, how would I be able to send the string value that is gathered in the script from the JS FileReader to the controller?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ An answer would be great when you have time.  Showing both methods if you can.  I'm doing this as a learning exercise and I've just gotten stumped here so any help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: yaa rignt now 11:00 pm my location, so I will start 1-2 hours have other stuff to do. but hopefully before bed time, if my brain keep working. Stay connected if i get question later.

Comment: is the json in your question the one you upload?

Comment: Yes, it's the JSON file generated from just dummy input from the other view in the application.  I excluded that to make the scope of the question more focused since that piece already works and the issue comes after I've got the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my answer. I went through your code and there are quite few issues. If I need to fix every thing for you it gone take some time. but here are some suggestion and you can take it to the next level.

1. You are trying to update a file with multipart form but you are trying to fetch a string. It is correct that you the file contains the string of json, but it is still a file. so we need to handle that part.
2. So you are both trying to show data using JavaScript and in view. In my example I have focused on showing data in your `IndexDeserialized` and JavaScript part is left for another question.

Here what I did and suggest:

In your controller, remove following method and replace it with the one I posted:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ImportForm(string jsonString)
{
    TableDemo model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TableDemo>(jsonString);
    return View("IndexDeserialized", model);
}
```

The new method, this is just simple example that can read the file you uploaded and return the result of it to the same page.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportFormOnPost()
{
    string jsonString = string.Empty;

    if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0] != null)
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
        await using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
            jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }


    TableDemo model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TableDemo>(jsonString);
    return View("IndexDeserialized", model);
}
```

In your ImportForm, you are missing action, in this case we are posting to `ImportFormOnPost` method:

```
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ImportFormOnPost">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" />
    </div>
    <div id="jsonContent">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:15px">
        <output form="uploadForm" name="result"></output>
    </div>
</form>
```

And finally we are presenting your data in `IndexDeserialized`:

```
@model FileUploaderApp.Models.TableDemo
<p>Number for locations: @Model?.Locations?.Count</p>

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var user in @Model.Users)
    {
        <p>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</p>
    }
}
```

It is possible to show your data as JSON object in using JavaScript in your front-end, but I think this part is a question for its own.

And remember this is just example, you can do a lot on top of it.

The final result looks like this:

[image]

For what I did, I got some reading from Microsoft about [file uploading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1) check this [resource](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/) code example of file upload.

Comment: Hey, thank you.  This worked.  One thing that threw me off was that the `IFormFile myFile` came through as null.  Is it even needed as a parameter if it's not being used in the code?  Instead you just grab the file from `HttpContext.Request`.

Comment: I am happy that it works for you. My bad I worked with different examples, one of them is IFormFile, so I have update the code, I have updated the code. but conceptually is the same.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) provides a simple way of doing what you ask,

"*Provides functionality to serialize objects or value types to JSON and to deserialize JSON into objects or value types.*"

Using the `JsonSerializer` API you can use `Serialize()` which returns a `string` and `Deserialize()` which returns an `object`.

A quick example would be:

```
TableDemo table = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonInputString, typeof(TableDemo), options);
```

[More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-write-net-objects-to-json-serialize) on this API.

If you're using .NET Framework (rather than .NET Core) you'll need to install the NuGet package in the Package Manager console:

`> Install-Package System.Text.Json -Version 4.7.2`

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the answer.  I've read that documentation the issue I'm having is that when I tried to have a controller action that accepted the JSON string, it was always null.  I don't know if I just made a silly mistake or what but I can't get the JSON string sent to the controller.  I'll edit the question with one of the controller actions I attempted to handle this.